# Trouble with responsivitizing my twentythirteen header

Tags: responsive, custom-header, theme-twenty-thirteen

I'm using the **twentythirteen** theme and trying to get the header to adapt to screen resolution.

I've uploaded several image files with the required resolutions, and changed my **custom-header.php** source code according to what is suggested [here](http://www.findurlaptop.com/tech/2013/08/23/responsive-header-background-wordpress-twenty-thirteen/).

The website, www.ensemblepourviroflay.org/wp/ (can't link more than twice with newbie account), does not seem to be displaying any of the images, at whichever resolution. I have pasted the content of my custom-header.php file [here](http://pastebin.com/XArB1sXF).

I would appreciate it if a kind stranger would have a look.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include all relevant code, *in the question*.

Answer (score 0):

I think the paths to your images specified in custom-header.php aren't correct. You can use home_url() to specify this path if necessary, eg